# Conjugate subgraphs and (maybe) a generalized Burnside's lemma?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

It's rather straightforward, I guess, to define *conjugate subgraphs* of a graph via its *conjugate nodes*. (Two nodes $x,y$ are conjugate when there is an automorphism $g$ such that $x = g(y)$.)

> **Definition:** Two subgraphs $G,G'$ of a graph $H$ are conjugate when there is a bijection $f: V(G) \rightarrow V(G')$ such that $x,f(x)$
>   are conjugate for all $x \in V(G)$.

Note that being conjugate is more than being isomorphic.

> **Questions:** Is there another name for conjugate subgraphs? And where do they play
>   a role?

Is there, for example, something like a generalized [Burnside's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma) which connects the number of "subgraph orbits" - with subgraphs of fixed order, eventually - with something else?

Comment: Wouldn’t it be more natural to say that $G$ and $G'$ are conjugate if there is an automorphism $g$ of $H$ such that $g(V(G))=V(G')$?

Comment: That depends. $g(V(G)) = V(G')$ seems very condensed. At first sight, it's an equality between sets, isn't it?

Comment: In the same orbit (of the natural action of AUT$(H)$ on subgraphs? But if *conjugate* is good enough for vertices then it should be good enough for subgraphs.

Comment: @Emil: If you are right and your definition is equivalent to mine, I would have to think about it more deeply (not to say "meditate"). At least, your definition seems more like a natural generalization. But if spelled out - how does it meet the intention?

Comment: I think Polya Enumeration can fit the bill for a generalization of Burnside's lemma.

Comment: As I understand it, your definition implies that any two subgraphs of the circular graph $C_n$ having the same number of vertices are "conjugate", since any two vertices of $C_n$ are conjugate. So conjugate subgraphs in your sense may not be isomorphic. Is this really your intention? 

Comment: @Hans: My definition is not equivalent to yours, the condition is stronger (it requires all the vertex pairs to be conjugate via the same automorphism). What I am saying is that the concept you defined looks quite weird to me, whereas my proposal is close to the definition of conjugate subgroups (the only difference being that for groups, only inner automorphisms are taken into account), which I assumed was your original motivation. Also, note that what I wrote is equivalent to Aaron’s description (being in the same orbit of the natural action of Aut($H$) on subgraphs).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable corrections. Starting with Emil's more appropriate and natural definition (which is equivalent to Aaron's) the questions remain: Is there another name for conjugate subgraphs? And where do they play a role? Or is Aaron's hint to Polya enumeration all there is to say?

Comment: @F: You guessed correctly: this was not my intention, I've been misled.

Comment: I’m not quite sure what kind of generalization of Burnside’s lemma you are after, but if you just want to count the number of subgraphs (with or without specified order) up to conjugation, you can apply Burnside’s lemma directly to the action of $\mathrm{Aut}(H)$ on subgraphs.

Comment: @Emil: I really appreciate your comments (and answers), but I am insecure where to post my questions: posting them at math.stackexchange reveals mostly (almost) nothing - few views, very few comments and answers. But posting them at MO seems overkill: you experts seem annoyed. Nevertheless you give valuable comments, what I do appreciate a lot! So, what do you recommend? 

Comment: @Hans: I’m not sure, I’d say that your questions are borderline for MO. For this particular question, the problem is not that much in the level, but in its lack of specificity: as explained in the FAQ, you should ask “well-defined questions ... that actually have a specific answer”, rather than open-ended requests like “where do they play a role”. I can’t comment on MSE as I’m not active there, so I’m not familiar with the situation.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/169016/a-generalized-burnsides-lemma