# A generalized Burnside's lemma

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a set $X$, and let $S\subseteq G$ be a union of conjugacy classes.  Then I believe I can prove:

$$ \sum_{[x]\in X/G} \frac{|G_x \cap S|}{|G_x|} = \sum_{g\in S} \frac{|X^g|}{|G|} $$

where $G_x$ is the stabilizer of $x\in X$ and $X^g$ is the fixed-point set of $g\in G$.  The assumption on $S$ makes ${|G_x \cap S|}$ depend only on the orbit $[x]$ of $x$.

When $S=G$, this reduces to the orbit-counting theorem.  Does the general form have a name?  Or is it a special case of something that has a name?  Is there somewhere I can cite for it?

Comment: Reading your second sentence, I am reminded of this reminiscence (http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1988-19-02/S0273-0979-1988-15735-7/S0273-0979-1988-15735-7.pdf) of Hugo Rossi on Errett Bishop: "In this time I also learned that when Errett said that he thought he could prove something, he meant that he could prove it, but that he was not yet happy with the exposition."

Comment: One special case: Take the conjugacy action of $G$ on itself. Then the right-hand side is the number of classes making up $S$, say $s$. Dividing by $|S|$ shows that the probability that elements $g \in G$ and $h \in S$ (chosen uniformly at random) commute is $s/|S|$.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure that the following remarks contribute much of value, but observe that the real content of the given formula is already there in the case where $S$ consists of just one class and $X$ is a single $G$-orbit. To get the given general formula, just sum over all classes in $S$ and all orbits in $X$.

To prove the formula in the one-class, one-orbit case, note that $|X^s|$ is constant for $s \in S$ since $S$ is a single class, so the right side of the desired equation is just 
$|S||X^s|/|G|$, where $s$ is an arbitrary element of $S$. Also, since $X$ is a single orbit, the left side is $|G_x \cap S|/|G_x|$, where $x \in X$ is arbitrary. What we want, therefore, is
$$
\frac{|G_x \cap S|}{|G_x|} = \frac{|S||X^s|}{|G|}\,.
$$
Since $|X| = |G|/G_x|$, this is equivalent to $|X||G_x \cap S| = |S||X^s|$. This is clearly true, however, because both sides equal the cardinality of the set of ordered pairs
$$
P = \{ (x,s) \mid x \in X, s \in S, x^s = x\}.
$$
Note that the usual proof of the orbit counting theorem also involves counting a set of ordered pairs in two ways.

Comment: Yeah, as I said, I know how to prove it.  I'm wondering whether it has a name or a reference I can cite.